# Oracle Sequence Coupled with Manual Insertion

Tags: database, oracle, insert, sequence

In Oracle, if I create a table with an ID field and I create a sequence object for that field to automatically increment by 1 and start at 1.

IE: ID: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, etc...

then for the first record of the table, I manually do an insert, IE:

```
insert into table(ID, etc...) values (1, etc...)
```

Will the sequence object automatically skip to the next available ID (2) if the sequence object is used for the next insertion?

Comment: The simple answer is no. A sequence is not tied in anyway to a table. They are two separate objects that are designed to be used in conjunction. If you need this sort of fail over, your application would need to handle a primary key violation and request a new value. Otherwise, just always use the sequence.

Comment: Use a trigger to enforce use of the sequence, and ignore the value supplied in the insert.

Comment: Thank you guys. That was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This requirement is often found, when migrating data. You migrate the data with no sequence generated document number. After migration you use a sequence to generate document/row numbers. To avoid conflict use a number-range for the sequence, that is disjunct from your migration number range.

Answer (score 0):

You may create a trigger to auto increment your sequence value.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER <tgr_name>
BEFORE INSERT ON <table> 
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
  SELECT seq_name.NEXTVAL
  INTO   :new.id
  FROM   dual;
END;
/
```